# Restrict access to full list/database, but have a search form to show results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, custom-list

Not sure whether my keywords are completely off, i'm quite new to SharePoint and have been using Lynda to get a quick grip of the program.

I have a brief which requires a frontend search/filters page (keywords, date, attributes based upon the data etc), which needs to find results from a large list of testimonials in different languages applying to different areas of a large business. However the client doesn't want the end user to be able to view all the results (No combination of the search results will display all the data).

This is a relatively easy thing to do in something like PHP/JS with a database, however i can't seem to find anything to point me in the right direction for SharePoint. Could anyone link me to any useful tutorials? Or let me know whether this will be something that could be achievable at all? - as i know SharePoint isn't really comparable to working on a normal website.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise edition, and can get any level of access granted to perform changes.

Comment: does end user have access to those content?

Comment: they will need access to the content to view it in the search results, i'm assuming? could they not view the content but still see search results containing the content?

they just need to not see the full list. Only a select few at a time using a search box and filters.

Comment: Search in SharePoint Server 2013 performs security trimming, which prevents users from seeing information that they do not have access to in the system. Security trimming is discussed further in this article.

Comment: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-security-trim-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: I'm not sure that's answering the question, the users should have access to the data.
maybe if i rephrase it like this: if you search something on google you get the results for that keyword, but you never see the full database of potential results, right? I need something like this.
So only a results page, which returns results based on a query. There should be no access to the full list/library. It seems a simple thing to do, in theory, i'm hoping i've just been searching the wrong keywords to find the answer.